# sqlite in c++ - parallel inserts from different applications, what will happen?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm opening the sqlite database file with `sqlite3_open` and inserting data with a `sqlite3_exec`.

The file is a global log file and many users are writting to it.

Now I wonder, what happens if two different users with two different program instances try to insert data at the same time... Is the opening failing for the second user? Or the inserting?

What will happen in this case?

Is there a way to handle the problem, if this scenario is not working? Without a server side database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases yes. It uses file locking, but it is broken on some systems, see http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: ok, thanks... will have a look on the `sqlite3_busy_handler()` and the `sqlite3_busy_timeout() `, those looks interesting...

Answer (score 0):

In short, the lock is created when you start a transaction, and released immediately after. While locked, other instances can neither read nor write to the db (in "big" db, they can still read). However, you can connect sqlite in [exclusive mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode). 
When you want to write to db, which is locked by another process, the execution halts for a specified timeout, by default 5 seconds. If lock is released, it proceeds with writing, if not it raises error.